# Scroll Recycleview to Top position when activity starts using Linearlayoutmanager

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I"m retrieving **Firebase RealTime Database** to my **Recycleview Adapter Class**. I want to sort the data by date with latest post at top. I'm using

```
llm.setReverseLayout(true);
```

which works but  now when activity opens then `recycleview` automatically scrolls to bottom itself. But I want it to force it to Top.

Here is my Code

```html
         rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
         LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
         llm.setReverseLayout(true);
         rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
         llm.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
         rv.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);
```

My whole code is

```html
public class SubjectBooks extends AppCompatActivity {
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    String user;
    DatabaseReference dbreference,dbref;
    RecyclerView rv;
    String subject;
    int child_count=0;
    ArrayList<Books> list;
    SubjectBooksAdapter staggeredBooksAdapter;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_subject_books);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getIntent().getStringExtra("subject")+" Area");
        getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#8abe50")));
     // this.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
     // this.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_share);



        fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        subject = getIntent().getStringExtra("subject").trim();

        dbreference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books").child(subject);
        dbreference.keepSynced(true);
        user = fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();

        list = new ArrayList<>();
        staggeredBooksAdapter = new SubjectBooksAdapter(list);

        rv = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        final ProgressDialog  progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Loading...", "Please wait...", true);
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please wait ...");
        progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        progressDialog.show();

        rv.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        rv.setLayoutManager(llm);
        rv.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);

        dbreference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                final Books b1 = dataSnapshot.getValue(Books.class);
              //  Log.e("Value is ",dataSnapshot.getKey()+" "+b1.getBauthor());
                //Log.e("Book"," received");
                if(!user.equals(b1.getSelleremail()) || (user.equals(b1.getSelleremail())) ) {

                    child_count++;
                    list.add(b1);
                    staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }


   
}
```

I used

```
/Solution one
mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0, 0);
//Solution Two
rv.scrollToPosition(0)
//Solution Three
setStackFromEnd(false)
//Solution Four
Collections.reverse();
```

But they didn't work.

Any Solution? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You only need `scrollToPosition(0);` **after** you set the adapter.

Comment: @forpas so I need to place your code after rv.setAdapter(staggeredBooksAdapter);??

Comment: Yes, provided that `staggeredBooksAdapter` already contains the data to be displayed.

Comment: @forpas I have updated my whole code and data is retrived at very last from firebase. ..so that is a major problem. should I place scrollToPosition(0); at very last?

Comment: After you have all the items in the adapter and you call setAdapter() or notify..(), then you use scrollToPosition(0);

Comment: so should I need to place after  staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();?

Comment: Yes, if this is the point were **all** the items are loaded in the adapter

Comment: it also didn't work i added   rv.scrollToPosition(0); after staggeredBooksAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); but still recycleview scross to bottom itself.

Comment: Try with smoothScrollToPosition(0). If this does not work also you must debug.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use set anything out of the box now pass false to `llm.setReverseLayout(false);`

When you get the data from firebase just use `Collections.reverse(passyourlist);` the list would be reversed inplace.
After that pass it to your adapter and it would work fine.

Comment: @Abhishek..it also didn't work. Still when I open adapter it scrolls to bottom and I have to manually scroll to top.

Comment: Updated the answer check it.